# SSRS Show Row with no Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I created a report which shows the amount of exceptions per exception type. The exception types are translated into numbers. Each exception type has its own query but I'm using a "UNION" to combine them into one column.

I am using the following code as the parent group in SSRS (=choose(Fields!ExceptionCode.Value
,"1.L"
,"2.D"
,"3.R"
,"4.C"
,"5.D2"
,"6.C2"
,"7.O"
,"8.O2"
,"9.G"
,"10.N"
,"11.I"
,"12.P")

However, when there are no exceptions(see #6 and #11), the row doesn't appear. Is there some sort of function that I can use for SSRS to include the row even if there is no data?

Here's how the table ends up looking:

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT  [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CustomerShortName
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalBalance
    - ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(OriginalBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS OrigBalance
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.QueryBalance 
    + ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(QueryBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold2 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS CurrBalance
,   CAST([report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature1 AS INT) AS ExceptionCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CreditRatingCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.DaysPastDue
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalLoanDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.MaturityDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.DateLastRenewal
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ShadowStatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OfficerCode
FROM [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaKeyAccount =     [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaKeyAccount = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
WHERE
    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate = @date
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode NOT IN (2,8)
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ParticipationCode <>'S'
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature1 <> ''

UNION

SELECT  [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CustomerShortName
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalBalance
    - ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(OriginalBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS OrigBalance
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.QueryBalance 
    + ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(QueryBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold2 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS CurrBalance
,   CAST([report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature2 AS INT) AS ExceptionCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CreditRatingCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.DaysPastDue
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalLoanDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.MaturityDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.DateLastRenewal
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ShadowStatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OfficerCode
FROM [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaKeyAccount = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaKeyAccount = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
WHERE
    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate = @date
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode NOT IN (2,8)
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ParticipationCode <>'S'
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature2 <> ''

UNION

SELECT  [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CustomerShortName
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalBalance
    - ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(OriginalBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS OrigBalance
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.QueryBalance 
    + ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(QueryBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold2 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS CurrBalance
,   CAST([report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature3 AS INT) AS ExceptionCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CreditRatingCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.DaysPastDue
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalLoanDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.MaturityDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.DateLastRenewal
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ShadowStatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OfficerCode
FROM [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaKeyAccount = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaKeyAccount = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
WHERE
    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate = @date
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode NOT IN (2,8)
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ParticipationCode <>'S'
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature3 <> ''

UNION

SELECT  [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CustomerShortName
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalBalance
    - ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(OriginalBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS OrigBalance
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.QueryBalance 
    + ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(QueryBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold2 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS CurrBalance
,   CAST([report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature4 AS INT) AS ExceptionCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CreditRatingCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.DaysPastDue
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalLoanDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.MaturityDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.DateLastRenewal
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ShadowStatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OfficerCode
FROM [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaKeyAccount = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaKeyAccount = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
WHERE
    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate = @date
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode NOT IN (2,8)
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ParticipationCode <>'S'
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature4 <> ''

UNION

SELECT  [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CustomerShortName
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalBalance
    - ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(OriginalBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS OrigBalance
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.QueryBalance 
    + ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(QueryBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold2 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS CurrBalance
,   CAST([report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature5 AS INT) AS ExceptionCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CreditRatingCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.DaysPastDue
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalLoanDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.MaturityDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.DateLastRenewal
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ShadowStatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OfficerCode
FROM [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaKeyAccount = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaKeyAccount = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
WHERE
    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate = @date
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode NOT IN (2,8)
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ParticipationCode <>'S'
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature5 <> ''

UNION

SELECT  [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CustomerShortName
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalBalance
    - ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(OriginalBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS OrigBalance
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.QueryBalance 
    + ISNULL((  SELECT  sum(QueryBalance) 
                FROM    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST AS LNMAST_Sold2 
                WHERE   JhaPostingDate = @date 
                        AND ParticipationCode = 'S'
                        AND PartialChargeOffAccountNumber = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.AccountNumber)
            ,0) 
    AS CurrBalance
,   CAST([report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature6 AS INT) AS ExceptionCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.CreditRatingCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.DaysPastDue
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalLoanDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.MaturityDate
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.DateLastRenewal
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ShadowStatusCode
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OfficerCode
FROM [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaKeyAccount = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNPDUE.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG
    ON [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaKeyAccount = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaKeyAccount
    AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.JhaPostingDate = [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate
WHERE
    [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.JhaPostingDate = @date
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.StatusCode NOT IN (2,8)
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.ParticipationCode <>'S'
AND [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNSMTG.SpecialFeature6 <> ''
ORDER BY AccountNumber
```

Comment: Your image isn't showing up for me, but typically, to ensure all rows exist, you need a table to anchor the report which includes all rows, and then match the data to that.  i.e. in SQL you would take all the exception types from a table and left join with the summary data.

Comment: Can you show us the query? It might be possible to wrap the balance columns in ISNULLs.

Comment: Sure. I have edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try wrapping all the instances of these

```
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.OriginalBalance
,   [report.silverlake.jha].vwLNMAST.QueryBalance
```

with ISNULL(). It looks like you do this with the right side operand you add or subtract from it, but if OriginalBalance or QueryBalance is NULL, then your arithmetic will yield a NULL